# Best way to region_highlight to a string?

Tags: zsh

I'd like to grab the colored text I see on the command line (due to the fast-syntax-highlighting plugin) and write it to a file in a widget (actually, I want to push it to my history preserving color). As I understand, that information is stored separately in `region_highlight`. For example, given:

```
foo () {
    echo $BUFFER $region_highlight
}

zle -N foo
bindkey '^E' foo
```

If I type, `ls clion` at my prompt and then hit C-e prior to hitting enter, I see:

```
ls clion/ls clion/ 0 2 fg=blue 3 9 fg=cyan,underline 8 9 fg=black
```

Where on my screen the first ls clion/ is syntax highlighted in the way you'd expect. How do I apply $region_highlight to $BUFFER to get a single line of standard, color code escaped text?

Comment: “I want to push it to my history preserving color”: What use is that? `region_highlight` is used only on the active command line. You cannot use it to highlight anything else.

Comment: @MarlonRichert Yes, that's the point. I want to take a string and its corresponding region_highlight and produce a color escaped string. I did eventually get this to work, I should probably post an answer. The result looks like this: https://asciinema.org/a/551906

Comment: That looks pretty cool. 